# ReflectionException Class Illuminate\Http\Factory does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and am getting the following error when attempting to use the Factory class for validation on user input.

ReflectionException
Class Illuminate\Http\Factory does not exist

```
Route::post('results.edited', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, 
\Illuminate\Http\Factory $validator) {
$validation = $validator->make($request->all(), [
    'comment' => 'required|min:10'
]);
if ($validation->fails()){
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation);
}
return redirect()->route('results.index')->with('info', 'Results Status Updated ' . 
$request->input('result') . $request->input('comment'));
})->name('results.update');
```

I've tried the following with no success:

$ composer update

$ composer dump-autoload

ReflectionException thrown with message "Class Illuminate\Http\Factory does not exist"

```
Stacktrace:
#50 ReflectionException in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php:25
#49 ReflectionParameter:getClass in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php:25
#48 Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in [internal]:0
#47 array_filter in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php:26
#46 Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters:fromAction in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:471
#45 Illuminate\Routing\Route:signatureParameters in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ImplicitRouteBinding.php:24
#44 Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding:resolveForRoute in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:787
#43 Illuminate\Routing\Router:substituteImplicitBindings in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:39
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#41 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#40 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:75
#39 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#38 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#37 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#36 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#35 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#34 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:56
#33 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#32 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#31 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#30 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#29 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#28 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66
#27 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#26 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#25 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#24 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:682
#23 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:657
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRoute in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:623
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:612
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21
#17 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57
#5 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ltcm/public/index.php:55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Illuminate\Http\Factory` class does not exist.

You need to inject `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` instead or even cleaner `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory`